# How to determine an integrating factor which is both function of x and y but not an exponential function e.g.($x^my^n$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms, line-integrals

I was watching   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=efBdnK1q504&list=PLj7p5OoL6vGykv4JM5MpY3I5j6mkLyKQU&index=8&t=0s video.

Now I would wonder what if special integrating factor had been a function of $x$ and $y$ other than some exponential function of $x$ and $y$. Then how should we get that? 
Suppose we have this differential $$(2y^3\sec y + 2\tan y)dx + \left(3xy^2\sec y + \dfrac{3y^2 \sec y}{x}+ x\right)dy= 0$$ What is the perfect procedure to find its integrating factor.

Comment: If I had to face this equation, the only thing I could do is to cry !

Comment: You asked this exact question before and accepted an answer. Why ask it again?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre  note the differential equation is different.

Comment: @user187604 : The method is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2y^3\sec y + 2\tan y)dx + \left(3xy^2\sec y + \dfrac{3y^2 \sec y}{x}+ x\right)dy= 0$$
$$\left(\frac{2y^3}{\cos(y)} + \frac{2\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}\right)dx + \left(\frac{3xy^2}{\cos(y)} + \dfrac{3y^2}{x\cos(y)}+ x\right)dy= 0$$
Reducing to the common denominator $x\cos(y)$ leads to :
$$\left(2xy^3 + 2x\sin(y)\right)dx + \left(3x^2y^2 + 3y^2+ x^2\cos(y)\right)dy= 0$$
Which is obviously exact:
$$d\left(x^2y^3+y^3 + x^2\sin(y)\right)=0$$
So, the integrating factor for the ODE in it's initial form was $x\cos(y)$ .

And the final result is :
$$x^2y^3+y^3 + x^2\sin(y)=c$$

A much more tedious method was to look for an integrating factor on the form $f(x)g(y)$ .

NOTE AFTER THE OP's COMMENT :

For the general ODE : $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ if the integrating factor if function of $y$ only, then the I.F. is $f(y)=\exp\left( \int \frac{N_x-M_y}{M}dy\right)$. If the I.F. is function of $x$ only then it is $g(x)=\exp\left( \int \frac{N_x-M_y}{N}dy\right)$. The formula is different for each form of I.F.

Using such ready-made formula is a short-cut possible only if the formula exists, that is if someone already solved the related kind of ODEs. As far as I know there is no ready-made formula for the general case. So, if no formula is available in the case we are considering, we have to solve it by ourselves without the help of a ready-made formula.

In case of academic exercises, generally the I.F. can be found by simple inspection, without arduous calculus. The ODE considered in your question is such an example of simple academic case.

Comment: My question is that do i I only have one way to estimate the function or I can have some specific formula to get the integrating factor like if it had been a function of y then it had been $$\int{N_x-M_y}/Mdx$$

Comment: @user187604 : See the note added to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help.